# How filter points in WMS?

Tags: openlayers

I am using WMS as overlay map. I want to filter the point shapefile which is in WMS. Currently using only WMS Code to display in whole. For that following is the code.

```
var jpl_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Administrative Layer",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/test/wms", 
                {layers: "maharashtra_administrative",transparent: true},{isBaseLayer:false});
                map.addLayer(jpl_wms);
```

this is point file. I want to pass parameter to restrict the points to be display(i.e point<100).
Please help me out if any one know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restrict points in WMS layer by attaching filter to it. First create filter based on some attribute in your shape file:

```
var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
   type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
   property: "id",
   value: 5
});
```

That will create filter object. You'll need to parse it to XML string. Following code will do the job:

```
 var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0();
 var filterAsXml = parser.write(filter);
 var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
 var filterAsString = xml.write(filterAsXml);
```

Now that you have a string you can attach it to your WMS layer:

```
jpl_wms.params["FILTER"] = filterAsString;
```

If the layer is already drawn you'll have do call `redraw()` method in order to apply filter:

```
jpl_wms.redraw();
```

Comment: Friend giving no result.  var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
      type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
      property: "type",
      value: "voltn"
                        });
    var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0();
   var filterAsXml = parser.write(filter);
  var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
  var filterAsString = xml.write(filterAsXml);
  mah2.params["FILTER"] = filterAsString;
        mah2.redraw(); is this write